# HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-identity, adfs

I created an MVC app to integrate an ADFS SSO using sustainsys. its working in my test dev server but when i tried to deploy it to a different IIS server.

the working app is deloyed in IIS 10 in windows server 2016. i was told that this web server has an AD server linekd to it. my mvc app is working fine as expected, claims are being retrieved after signing in the adfs. this was a test dev server so i cannot use it, i was given another dev server where i need to deploy the mvc app.

This server is windows 2019, it doesnt have any AD server attached to it. i deployed the mvc app like how i deployed in the other server and when i tested my app the claims (`HttpContext.User.Identity`) is null. the MVC app is already trusted in the ADFS server.

in the web config, i have authentication = forms, its the setting i followed in the documentation of sustainsys.

I'm not sure what configuration i need to do to make it work, its not code related because it is working locally and in the first server i have deployed to.

Edit:
i have the SAML Response witht he returned attributes,

```
  <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>value</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
                <AttributeValue>value</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn">
                <AttributeValue>value</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="Department">
                <AttributeValue>Search</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
```

Comment: There are tons of discussions on that topic already, so you should go over them first, https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/684 The developers also left hints on how to troubleshoot https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/troubleshooting.html

Comment: not sure how I can troubleshoot the code or sustainsys config if its working locally and working in a different IIS server.

Comment: You have a failed and successful pair, so even just comparing the logs mentioned in that troubleshooting guide should reveal enough hints on what's wrong.

Comment: thank you, i know whats wrong the UPN in the failed one is NULL. is it because the server does not have any AD server tied to it?

Comment: Since you mentioned that the server which failed doesn't have any AD server, I think that may be the cause. The field upn(user principal name) is one of basic fields of AD. So if you do not integrate with AD, it may not have this field.